# how to use materialscloud api in colab to convert poscar files into pwscf files?

Tags: python, dft

Facing  difficulty  while trying to make use of materialscloud api .

Tried every possible steps But couldn't able to connect even after following the procedure described in the [materialscloud website](https://www.materialscloud.org/explore/connect) in colab notebook . I think the api may helpful to generate Pwscf input file for DFT calculation using Quantum Espresso